# emoji is clipped in UILabel in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, emoji

Hello I'm working on chat app in which user can send smiley (emoji) to other user. For text its working perfect  but when it contains emoji then it is correct. I have used method for this

```
- (CGSize)getSizeForText:(NSString *)text maxWidth:(CGFloat)width font:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(float)fontSize {
    CGSize constraintSize;
    constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
    constraintSize.width = width;
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                      options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                   attributes:attributesDictionary
                                      context:nil];

    CGSize stringSize = frame.size;
    return stringSize;
}
```

and the results are something like [image: image 1] [image: image 2] [image: image 3]

As from images you can see what i want to say and what i need. I need some between two lines when there is emoji text in UILabel. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have given answer on this. But if some have some quick hack for this then that will be great for me.

Comment: adjust your font size.

Comment: have you tested this on real device ?

Comment: Yes this images are from device

Comment: how do you setup label  ?

Comment: label is in one cell and i have resize it according to content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a good work to do it manually and it looks good for me now. I have added linespacing for label text and it works good for me. I have set text like

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message_text]];
            NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
            [style setLineSpacing:4];
            [attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                               value:style
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [message_text length])];
            lblChatMSG.attributedText = attrString;
```

and my method to get height of text is

```
- (CGSize)getSizeForText:(NSString *)text maxWidth:(CGFloat)width font:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(float)fontSize {
    CGSize constraintSize;
    constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
    constraintSize.width = width;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 4;

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,paragraphStyle,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                      options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                   attributes:attributesDictionary
                                      context:nil];

    CGSize stringSize = frame.size;
    return stringSize;
}
```

And the result is [image: image result for emoji with good space in lines]

Comment: you can use literal syntax instead of `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys`. e.g. `@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle }`

Answer (score 1):

I just increased the required height of the label and adjusted its origin.

```
    // Expand label to avoid cutoff emojis
    label.frame.size.height += 8.0
    label.frame.origin.y -= 4.0
```

Comment: We need to limit it by some condition otherwise it will continue increasing height when cellforrow was called.

Comment: You can add this height after recalculating the `sizeThatFits` or after `layoutSubviews`. Just don't do it all the time.